# C# - Failing at transferring data between forms

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I am new to C# and already starting to have some troubles. I have googled for some hours how to get this done but my program refuses to obey his master.

My *MainForm* has a *ListBox*. *Form2* uses a *Open File Dialog* and should return the file path to the *ListBox* in *MainForm*

This is the code I have in *Form2*

```c#
public void BrowseFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
         string path = BrowseFileDialog.FileName;
         MainForm frm = new MainForm();
         frm.AppListAdd(path);
    }
```

This is the *MainForm*

```c#
public void AppListAdd (string path)
    {
        AppList.Items.Add(path);
    }
```

Note: AppList = ListBox

I don't get any error, yet the *ListBox* remains empty.

Comment: Shouldn´t it be frm.AppList.Items.Add(path);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `MainForm` and not showing it, while the visible/existing/real main form is not affected.

Add to `Form2` class:

```
public MainForm MainForm { get; set; }
```

When you create `Form2` do (presumably in a `MainForm`'s method):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.MainForm = this;
```

and

```
public void BrowseFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  string path = BrowseFileDialog.FileName;
  if (MainForm != null)
    MainForm.AppListAdd(path);
}
```